# How do I implement the versioning of the data in Spring Boot + Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, versioning

I know how the versions of the record will be saved. I chose the **"double table"** method

I have a **"post"** table, and I just need to create another table, exactly the same, and call it **"history"**. When you change the master record in the **"post"** table, a copy of the changed entry with a label is created, who changed it and when it is in the **"history"** table.[image]

The question is how to implement this in a project that uses a **spring boot.** If you have any examples or thoughts on how to implement this, please share with me.

The Internet describes only the methods themselves, without their solution.

---

**Please help me.**
If you have any comments then say them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring Data with Spring boot, you can use Hibernate envers' `@Audited` annotation for `Post` entity to persist the old value in another table ([here's](http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa) the documentation), e.g.:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class Post {
..
}
```

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/) are some examples.